# npm deprecate to go back a version

Tags: npm

My question is about the effect of `npm deprecate <pkg>[@<version>]`.

I have an npm package that I updated via `npm version <version>`. But in an unfortunate typo I upped the major version instead of the minor.

I really don't want to go up a major version, but now the npm registry shows the upped major version. Simply trying to set the version again to the correct (and overall lower) version number does nothing (which makes sense, since npm would consider it a lesser version).

If I use `npm deprecate <pkg>[@<version>]` on the late (incorrect) version will it make the lesser version (which is correct) be considered the "latest" again?

Comment: A few upvotes, that's good...but no answers :( I'll settle for an alternative way of removing the upped major version altogether if someone knows of one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to delete the unwanted version [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/unpublish.html) but `npm deprecate` is recommended option as it will not break